# latest version of modernizr and no-touch class

Tags: javascript, css, modernizr

Modernizr use to have a .no-touch class where if you nest hover states under it, it would ignore it on touch screen devices.

I have recently downloaded a new version of Modernizr but cant seem to get the .no-touch class working.

Have they removed/renamed it or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

[according to the release notes](https://modernizr.com/news/modernizr-3-new-release-site)

> Modernizr.touch has been removed in favor of Modernizr.touchevents

Answer (score 2):

You can use the class `touchevents` now (you have to include the touchevents module)